# How to use trim in store procedure sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
 SELECT * FROM (
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Auto_ID asc) as RowNum from (
Select Distinct a.* FROM sample a inner join samble_out b on a.***=b.*** and a.***=@*** and a.*** LIKE  @*** + '%' ) as emp
) as Employee
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex +
@pageSize) - 1
order by Auto_ID asc
```

What's wrong in my above query . If i tried in sql management getting out put but while tried from c# returning empty row. Weather need to use trim in like. Please help me

Comment: I don't see any `trim` here.

Comment: No i din't used here but i am passing the trim() parameter only

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has 2 `TRIM` functions

`LTRIM` => trimming left part of your string

`RTRIM` => trimming right part of your string

Here a simple `TRIM` Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@string))
END
```

example:

```
SELECT dbo.TRIM('  Trimmedstring  ')
```

Comment: sorry i din't understand weather need to trim at starting it self
`(
startRowIndex int,
pageSize int,
@totalCount int out,
emp_id varchar(15),
emp_name varchar(50),
loc_code varchar(50),
StatementType nvarchar(20) = ''
)`

Comment: @ilaya-bharathi sorry but i don't understand your problem

Comment: @IlayaBharathi, I think you mean to trim the values in your c# app and then send it to database. Yes obviously, it's better to trim in your business layer than in your database layer.

Comment: exactly @sqluser but i have trim in my c# app itself. It's working fine if din't pass extra parameter along with like statement . If passed means not working. I can't predict weather problem in c# or database. Any how the same query is used in my c# it'self & It's working fine